# Por qué no encuentra la ruta del archivo css/javascript

Tags: javascript, css, rutas, static

He seguido un tutorial de cómo hacer una página estática para luego desplegarla. Los archivos .html que me genera (con el comando npm run docs:dev), me lo genera con errores ya que no encuentra la ruta pero si busco la ruta en el explorador de archivos aparece.

He conseguido no tener errores en estático, pero me sigue pasando el mismo problema al generar los archivos .html (con el comando npm run docs:build). No encuentra la ruta de los archivos css o javascript.
Los errores:
[image]

Comment: tu ruta es `/adocs mbe` o `/adocs_mbe` ? me refiero a que si estas usando espacios

Comment: Hola @rod, te sugiero que hagas una pasada por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, para saber como preguntar, de esa manera, nos ayudas a ayudarte y evitas que tu pregunta termine cerrada.

Comment: Esas rutas buscan el fichero en tu sistema directamente (el protocolo file:///...), lo que causa un error CORS. Esos ficheros deberían ser *servidos* por el mismo servidor web que estés usando para poder se accedidos

Comment: @EvilFearz la ruta es adocs_mbe

Comment: @Pablo Lozano entonces debería subir la carpeta de la que proviene y pasarle la ruta relativa de los archivos?